# Execute shellscript inside shellscript

Tags: bash, shell

I've been scratching my head on this for a while.
I have a script that is run by a root cron job.
The script executes, but there is a script inside the script that wont execute.
Here is what we will call scriptA

```
#!/bin/bash
lines=`wc -l < /var/www/log/addme`;
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`

if [[ $lines > 4 ]];
then
echo " " > /var/www/log/addme
RESTART=/var/www/log/restart.sh
$RESTART
else
echo "No new hosts added" | wall
fi
```

Basically what the restart.sh script does is to restart a service.
Everything works just fine when I run them from terminal, but not as cron jobs...
I also tried to just put

```
./restart.sh
/var/www/log/restart.sh
```

But with same result.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Does the cron job run as root or as some other user? Does the user have access to /var/www/log? Have you tried logging what happens when the first script tries to call the second one (change `$RESTART` to `$RESTART >/var/tmp/foo.log 2>&1`)?

Comment: What are the permissions on `/var/www/log/restart.sh`?  Is it executable?  If not, you can `chmod +x` it, or run it with `bash $RESTART` in your scriptA.

Comment: Also, set a `MAILTO` variable inside your crontab, so that you can see what errors are generated by the job.

Comment: Besides, the `[[ $lines > 4 ]]` is doing a lexical comparison, which would bring problems with $lines >= 10. You may replace the '>' with '-gt'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're running into problems with the minimal environment that cron runs its jobs with. The biggest thing is that the PATH is very minimal, and is your script is probably using some commands that can't be found.

If this is the problem, there are several ways to fix it: the easiest is generally to add an appropriate definition of PATH to the crontab file, before the entry that runs your script. Something like this:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
0 * * * *       /var/www/log/scriptA
```

The second is to add a similar assignment at the beginning of scriptA. The third option is to go through both of the scripts, and use full paths for all of the commands you use (e.g. `/usr/bin/wc` instead of just `wc`).

BTW, there is also a problem with the test `[[ $lines > 4 ]]` -- inside `[[ ]]`, `>` does a string (alphabetical) comparison, not a numeric comparison. This is a problem because, alphabetically, 10 is less than 4. Use either `[[ $lines -gt 4 ]]` or `(( lines > 4 ))` to get a numeric comparison.

Comment: This solved my problem and also the problem I did not know exist. Thanks a lot! I'll remember the cron PATH's in the future.